# UI Automation doesn't see hidden windows?

Tags: automation, ui-automation, shellexecuteex

I have winforms application that is signed and has manifest with level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false".

I want to start another application with hidden window and to work with it using UI Automation API.

```
        Process procinst = new Process();
        procinst.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            UseShellExecute = true,
            ErrorDialog = true,
            Verb = "runas",
            FileName = appfilepath
        };           
        procinst.Start();
```

The new process with hidden window can be seen in Spy++ but not in UISpy and I cannot also find it using FindFirst method:

```
mainwnd = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "apptitle"));
```

When ProcessWindowStyle is Minimized everything goes fine, when it is Hidden - everything stops. 
Is it expected UI Automation behavior? UI Automation cannot access hidden windows? Is there any way to hack it?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly asking for hidden windows?

Comment: What does it mean, explicitly? I can access window by FindFirst or by window handler. ShellExecuteEx doesn't return window handler, so I have only first option. Beside that hidden windows are not shown in UISpy. May be such feature is not supported by UI Automation by design?

Comment: YES: You can get invisible windows. Enumerate the toplevel windows (for example with EnumWindows() and GetWindowThreadProcessId() to check to which process the window belongs) and then use AutomationElement.FromHandle() to get an automation instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's sad but that's true:

> **There is not really such a thing as an “invisible” or “background” elements in UIA** – when an element is gone, it will no longer be in the UIA tree. This is a good thing for assistive technologies (less pruning of the tree required), but can be troublesome for UI Automation frameworks. Historically we would tend to cache UI elements so we could get back to them again faster. When needed, one could call a mix of ShowWindow and accSelect with SELFLAG_TAKEFOCUS. This no longer works. If, say, a tool window is tabbed and not in the foreground; our cached element for it will because invalid, and if it’s requested we need to a) bring it into the foreground and b) find the element from scratch again.

[WPF in Visual Studio 2010 – Part 6 : Automated UI Testing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/30/wpf-in-visual-studio-2010-part-6-automated-ui-testing.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN, "programmatically hidden" [UI elements should not be in the UI Automation tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In particular:

> UIA_IsOffscreenPropertyId  (30022) Identifies the IsOffscreen
>   property, which is a Boolean value that indicates whether the
>   automation element is entirely scrolled out of view (for example, an
>   item in a list box that is outside the viewport of the container
>   object) or collapsed out of view (for example, an item in a tree view
>   or menu, or in a minimized window). If the element has a clickable
>   point that can cause it to receive the focus, the element is
>   considered to be on-screen while a portion of the element is off
>   screen.  The value of the property is not affected by occlusion by
>   other windows, or by whether the element is visible on a specific
>   monitor.  If the IsOffscreen property is TRUE, the UI element is
>   scrolled off-screen or collapsed. The element is temporarily hidden,
>   yet it remains in the end-users perception and continues to be
>   included in the UI model. The object can be brought back into view by
>   scrolling, clicking a drop-down, and so on.  **Objects that the end-user
>   does not perceive at all, or that are "programmatically hidden" (for
>   example, a dialog box that has been dismissed, but the underlining
>   object is still cached by the application) should not be in the
>   automation element tree in the first place (instead of setting the
>   state of IsOffscreen to TRUE).**

Comment: It is mostly like you cite that invisible elements do not appear. But it depends on how it is implemented on the server side. For example Firefox returns a lot of invisible UIA Elements. They simply have a bounding rectangle of 0 x 0 pixels.

Comment: @Elmue I would then argue that Firefox has a poor implementation of UI Automation, and that you should open a bug on Firefox.   (Of course, you'll still have to work around it, but in general, the UIA philosophy is as stated above.)

Comment: Ohhhh, then you can write bugreports all around. Also Microsoft has implement a LOT of elements that report a size of 0 x 0 pixels. For example in a WPF ComoboBox the drop down items are invisible (Size= 0x0 pixels) until the list in the ComboBox is shown. Also in a WPF DataGrid all itmes that are scrolled out of view have size = 0x0 pixels.