# Open a popup window from a hidden window

Tags: vb.net, winapi, hide, showwindow

I am developing a tool in VB.NET to automate some tasks of another application, however, I would like to do this in a hidden way. I open the editor and then, through `ShowWindow (Editor, SW_HIDE)`, I hide its window.

The problem is that in this Editor there is a button for "Save As", which opens a popup window to put the Name and Click Save.

When the Editor is not hidden it works perfectly. However, when the Editor is hidden, the popup window does not load (I cannot find its handle).

Is it possible to somehow perform this task, preferably with the hidden popup window too?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

PS1: The "Save As" button is not possible to view in Spy ++, only when I use Inspect.

Seeking to understand the difference between them I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174895/what-type-of-controls-dont-show-up-in-spy-inspect) post.

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606352/ui-automation-doesnt-see-hidden-windows) post I understood that UIA do not see hidden elements.

[image: Spy ++ and Inspect screens]

Any suggestions for my project?

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub AtualizarGrafico()

Dim nomejanela As String = ""
    For Each p As Process In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses
        If (p.MainWindowTitle <> "") Or (p.MainWindowTitle <> " ") Then
            If Mid(p.MainWindowTitle, 1, 9) = "ProfitPro" Then
                nomejanela = p.MainWindowTitle
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If FindWindow(vbNullString, nomejanela) = False Then
        MsgBox("A Plataforma não está aberta.")
        Exit Sub

    End If

    Dim Profit As Integer = FindWindow(vbNullString, nomejanela) 'LEVEL 1
    Dim Container As Integer = Win32.FindWindowEx(Profit, vbNullString, "MDIClient", vbNullString) 'LEVEL 1.1
    Dim Editor As Integer = Win32.FindWindowEx(Container, vbNullString, "TLanguageEditorForm", vbNullString) ' LEVEL 1.1.1

    Win32.ShowWindow(Editor, Win32.SW_HIDE)
    Win32.SetForegroundWindow(Container)
    Win32.SendMessage(Container, Win32.WM_ACTIVATE, 0, 0)

    'Shortcut to open
    If Editor = 0 Then
        SendKeys.Send("^q")
    End If

    Dim EditorPainel As Integer = Win32.FindWindowEx(Editor, vbNullString, "TPanel", "EditorPanel") 'LEVEL 1.1.1.1
    Dim EditorIntraPainel As Integer = Win32.FindWindowEx(EditorPainel, vbNullString, "TPanel", "EditorInnerPanel") 'LEVEL 1.1.1.1.1.1
    Dim EditorEstrategia As Integer = Win32.FindWindowEx(EditorIntraPainel, vbNullString, "TLanguageEditor", "") 'LEVEL 1.1.1.1.1.1.1

    Dim Painel As Integer = Win32.FindWindowEx(Editor, Nothing, "TPanel", "") 'LEVEL 1.1.1.2
    Dim ToolBar As Integer = Win32.FindWindowEx(Painel, Nothing, "TTBToolBar", "ToolBar1") 'LEVEL 1.1.1.2.1

    'wait 'til load the form
    Thread.Sleep(1000)

    Win32.SetForegroundWindow(EditorEstrategia)
    Win32.SetActiveWindow(EditorEstrategia)

    SendKeys.SendWait("^{HOME}") '   
    SendKeys.SendWait("^+{END}") '  
    SendKeys.SendWait("{DEL}")
    SendKeys.SendWait("^v")

    'ROTINA PARA SALVAR

    'backSaveAs:
    Dim HandleBtnSalvarComo = AutomationElement.FromHandle(ToolBar)
    Dim FindSaveAs = HandleBtnSalvarComo.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Salvar como..."))
    Dim btnSaveAs As InvokePattern = DirectCast(FindSaveAs.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern), InvokePattern)
    btnSaveAs.Invoke()

    Thread.Sleep(1000)

    Dim windowSaveAs As Integer = Win32.FindWindow(vbNullString, "Salvar Como") 'LEVEL 2
    Dim fieldNameSaveAs As Integer = Win32.FindWindowEx(windowSaveAs, vbNullString, "TEdit", vbNullString) 'LEVEL 2.1

    'VARIÁVEL DO NOME DA ESTRATÉGIA
    Win32.SendMessageT(fieldNameSaveAs, Win32.WM_SETTEXT, 0, numero_editor & "EE")

    Dim HandleBtnSave = AutomationElement.FromHandle(windowSaveAs)
    Dim FindSave = HandleBtnSave.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Salvar"))
    Dim btnSave As InvokePattern = DirectCast(FindSave.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern), InvokePattern)
    Win32.ShowWindow(Editor, Win32.SW_SHOW)
    btnSave.Invoke()
End Sub
```

Comment: I would probably suggest doing things a bit differently. Check [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?636812) out and see if you think it would be a good idea for your app. You can put the functionality to display the dialogue in a common location and then invoke it from a menu item on the tray icon and the button on the form.

Comment: *"preferably with the hidden popup window too"*. How would you do a "Save As" without a dialogue for the user to tell you what to save it as? If you're not getting a file name then it's just a "Save", not a "Save As". If you don't want to show the user a form then don't create a form. Put the code to save somewhere else and invoke it without an extra dialogue.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, but the Editor and popup window do not belong to my application.
The "Name" field I am passing through SendMessageT (SaveAsName, Win32.WM_SETTEXT, 0, name), after I click on the Save button through AutomationElement (Invoke). I don't have the option of not opening the popup window to Save As.
I would like to do all this in a hidden way, Editor and popup window to Save As.

Comment: A popup window is an owned window. An owned window is hidden when its owner is hidden. Your observation, that this popup window did not load is probably wrong. The code you use to discover the window is probably wrong. Nothing we can do without seeing it. Well, we can do *something* at least: Recommend how to do it properly, i.e. use [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/what-are-winevents).

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example]? Since it's still unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I edited the topic providing more information.

Comment: Did  your popup window has indeed been created. You need to check your return value. As I tested, calling `SetForegroundWindow` fails after I hide the  window.

Comment: From what I read, according to the post edition, my window is not loading because UIA does not accept hidden windows. This is my problem now: according to the Inspect image, the button that calls the popup window is only found with UI Automation ... Is there any other way to invoke this button?

Comment: You may need to implement the Save As method yourself. Or, a workaround, use [`SetLayeredWindowAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setlayeredwindowattributes) to set the window transparent instead of hide:`int style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE); SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE,style| WS_EX_LAYERED| WS_EX_TRANSPARENT); SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, 0, LWA_ALPHA);`